# How to touch a file/update its modification time on disk in Nim?

Tags: fileinfo, nim-lang, filemtime

I'd like to update the modification time of some files in Nim, without actually modifying them, like Unix `touch`. I see there is an [`os.getLastModificationTime`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#getLastModificationTime,string) function, or more broadly [`os.getFileInfo`](https://nim-lang.org/docs/os.html#getFileInfo,string), but I do not see corresponding set functions.

How do you touch a file in Nim? (If platform matters, I am currently working on Windows, sadly.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately that is system specific in the current Nim version 0.18.0. On posix you'd do:

```
import posix
utimes("filename", nil)
```

In the next release you can use the platform independent `os.setLastModificationTime`: https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/pull/7543

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Do you happen to know what the plan is for a release date of this version? Also do you know if the best way to get a prerelease build to build it myself?

Comment: Don't know when, you can use an older version of Nim to compile it yourself: https://github.com/nim-lang/nim#compiling

Comment: Another option is of course to use choosenim. With that utility you can easily switch between versions, including the latest development version. Simply run `choosenim devel` to switch to your devel branch, or `choosenim update devel` to compile the newest source on GitHub and switch to that.

Answer (score 4):

Piggybacking on def-'s answer, here is a complete example showing how you can update file modification time to "now", of file passed as first argument:

```
import os
import times

let file = commandLineParams()[0]
setLastModificationTime(file, now().toTime())
```

Behind the scenes (with Nim 0.19) on posix systems this delegates to `posix.utimes()` and will changes the 3 file timestamps for `access`, `modify`, `change`.
On Windows the "behind the scenes" details will differ, reading source code I *think* it will only change "last write time", not "last access time".